# Can't format date in <input>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem binding my  to a DateTime in Angular.

In Fiddler, my DateTime looks like this:

```
lastEnquiryDate: 2015-03-04T16:01:18.403Z
```

The following works:

```
<input ng-model="customer.lastEnquiryDate" class="form-control input-sm" id="customer-last-enquiry-date" readonly></input>
```

but produces an ugly result.

What I would like to do is filter the customer.lastEnquiryDate so that it is pretty, like this:

```
<input ng-model="customer.lastEnquiryDate | date" class="form-control input-sm" id="customer-last-enquiry-date" readonly></input>
```

but this produces [this error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngModel/nonassign?p0=customer.lastEnquiryDate%20%7CNaNate&p1=%3Cinput%20ng-model%3D%25customer.lastEnquiryDate%20%7C%DAte%22%20class%3D%25form-control%25input-sm%20ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%20id%3D%25customer-last-enquiry-date%22%20readonly%3D%22%22%3E). Now I understand why this error is being generated but I don't know the workaround. I have tried using ng-bind, but this produces a blank input.

How do I format the date in this input? As it happens, my date field is read only, so a solution using ng-bind would be ok.

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Is it better with a filter like this ?  `date:'MM/dd/yyyy'`

Comment: If it's always readonly do you need to use and input and ngModel? Can you just bind it to a span or label using <span>{{customer.lastEnquiryDate | date}}</span>

Comment: I could use a span, but the input is part of a much larger form and look/feel wise it needs to be an input.

Comment: It looks like your using bootstrap??? I'm sure there is a class for making a span look like an input field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work:

```
  <input ng-model="customer.lastEnquiryDate" type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="customer-last-enquiry-date" readonly></input>
```

More details here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Comment: Actually I just looked in F12 and disovered that ng-model="customer.lastEnquiryDate | date" is throwing exceptions. It appears correctly in the input, but throws exceptions. Any one have any clue how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did, but it suddenly started working with ng-model="customer.lastEnquiryDate | date". Don't know why, but don't look a gift horse in the mouth, as they say.

Comment: This doesn't work. I just get a blank dd/mm/yyyy prompt in the field. Any further ideas?